# AJAX Async Front end PHP REST back end

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json, ajax

Planning to create a meta flight search website like http://www.momondo.com.au/

After doing a search, it will AJAX Async from different providers and display the results on the listing page.

Question I have is, what is the best way to achieve this in terms of which technology to use?

This is what I have in mind:

PHP Rest Server back end which returns JSON feed from each provider, ie:

```
www.abc.com/provider/1 (return json feed of flights)
www.abc.com/provider/2 (return json feed of flights)
www.abc.com/provider/3 (return json feed of flights)
```

Front end will be using AngularJS to AJAX those feed and populate a template with data from the feed and display it as soon as we get the results.

That is my solution to this puzzle, do you guys have any other ideas/smarter and better way to achieve a similar outcome?

Thanks

Comment: run with it...this question is too broad and also elicits too many opinions to be appropriate question for the site. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31035655/completion-blocks-in-php/31035719#31035719

And please add a question to your "question" - Advising on what to do is not allowed by Stack